# login.microsoftonline.com reject https://outlook.office.com/mail.write scope

Tags: php, email, outlook-restapi

I try to modify the sample from the [dev.outlook.com](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php) to send emails to selected contacts.
Unmodified example works fine, but when I added scope "*https://outlook.office.com/mail.write*" to **oauth.php** i receive error.

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is
>   not  valid. The scope openid //outlook.office.com/mail.read 
>   //outlook.office.com/mail.write is not valid.

Why it is rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual scope you want is `https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite`, and you should replace the `https://outlook.office.com/mail.read` one with that (since it includes read). You will probably also want `https://outlook.office.com/mail.send` if you plan on sending mail.